# Calculate Excel formulas in VBA but display only the value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This is my first post and I can't find an exact answer anywhere. I have an Excel spreadsheet that is becoming too large to operate because I have long formulas in millions of cells. I need to know how to calculate the formula using VBA but have only the value appear in Excel.  An example is I want to multiply column B by column C:

I have tried this code:

```
Range("D3:D6").Formula = Evaluate("=B3*C3")
```

It correctly calculates for the first cell, but for the other cells it still tries to calculate B3*C3 as a fixed reference rather than as a dynamic references that changes as the cell position changes.

How could I fix this? Thankyou.

Edit:

My actual spreadsheet looks like this:

[image: Excel Screenshot 2]

This formula needs to be applied down 17520 rows and across 300 columns, but I only want the values to appear in Excel.  The purpose of this is to reduce file size and reduce calculation time.

```
=IF(-SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0")>0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0"),0,IF(-SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0")-IF(WQ5<'Battery Specs'!$B$13,-'Battery Specs'!$B$15,IF(WQ5=ROUNDDOWN('Battery Specs'!$B$13,0)+1,-('Battery Specs'!$B$13-ROUNDDOWN('Battery Specs'!$B$13,0))*'Battery Specs'!$B$15,0))>0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0"),-(0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0")+SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0")),IF(WQ5<'Battery Specs'!$B$13,-'Battery Specs'!$B$15,IF(WQ5=ROUNDDOWN('Battery Specs'!$B$13,0)+1,-('Battery Specs'!$B$13-ROUNDDOWN('Battery Specs'!$B$13,0))*'Battery Specs'!$B$15,IF((0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0")+SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0"))>'Battery Specs'!$B$10,0,IF(((0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0")+SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0"))+$AIF5*0.9)>'Battery Specs'!$B$10,'Battery Specs'!$B$10-(0.9*SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,">0")+SUMIF(AIG$4:AIG4,"<0")),$AIF5))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Range("D3:D6").Formula = "=B3*C3"
Range("D3:D6").Value = Range("D3:D6").Value
```

or simply

```
Range("D3:D6").Formula = Evaluate("(B3:B6)*(C3:C6)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  However, I don't believe this will reduce the time taken in Excel for my large spreadsheet/formulas because the first line of your code places the formula in all the cells.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Tyce - Try the second option in answer `Range("D3:D6").Formula = Evaluate("(B3:B6)*(C3:C6)")`

Comment: And to improve performance even more it might be worth turning off the screenupdating while running the code. (Even better would be to collect the results in an array and write that in one go-or bulk if necessary-but I assume that would be a step too far).

Comment: @Mrig - Thank you again - Sorry my computer hadn't updated for your edit.  The 2nd line is great.  How could I apply it to many columns though without needing to individually list each column?  I'm just not sure how I could apply it to my actual spreadsheet with many IF statements and OFFSETS.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Using Evaluate to calculate the formulas and then transfer the values to Excel will be slower than having Excel calculate the formulas directly.

Here are a couple of things you could try:

a) Formulas
You only have 5 million formulas in 5 million cells - this is not an overwhelmingly large number but your formulas are very long and each formula references a large number of cells.
Your formula contains many repeated expressions and calculations - move them out to helper cells and try to simplify/shorten your formula.

b) VBA - don't use Evaluate - just grab the range of 5 million cells into a single variant array and use VBA Loops, arithmetic and logic to accomplish the same task as your formulas and then put the array back.

Comment: Thank you Charles.  Will creating helper cells reduce file size/increase calculation speed?  Because Each time I create a set of helper cells, there will be another 5 million of them.  As for VBA, unfortunately my VBA skills aren't good enough to create the desired loops without a lot of help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe best option is to keep formulas instead of using VBA to produce same formulas. Instead, when entering new data in SpreadSheet, be sure to set calculations to manual (go to `Formulas` tab=>`Calculation Options`=>`Manual`. This way you wont trigger calculations when entering/pasting new values, meaning your Excel file will operate just as fast as if there was no formulas. After you entered/pasted all new values, set `Calculations` to `Automatic`.

Comment: Hi Kresimir.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I have tried this but the spreadsheet is still excessively slow (Several hours for just to open it - It is now at 560MB) and I believe the best way to reduce size at the moment is to prevent Excel having to store the millions of long formulas I am using.  Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are right. If file is that big, try to save it as XLSB format, which is by default compressed format. You should get some improvement in terms of speed of opening file/reduced size and better calculation speed(not sure about last one).

Comment: I'd say at a size like 560MB it's worth trying to split this data into seperate workbooks or store it in something a bit quicker than Excel

Comment: @B Slater thanks.  That may be what i'll have to do with the spreadsheet if I can get it working for long enough.  What do you recommend storing/calculating it in otherwise?  I'm inexperienced with other programs.  Is Matlab a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 3 to 6
    Range("D" & i).Value = Range("B" & i).Value * Range("C" & i).Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative is to name your formula, for instance, instead of saying =B3*C3, you can give it a name say times value, and then say =timesvalue. Next, remove the formula and leave the value only. E.g. range("D3:D30").value=range("D3:D30").value